# How to make sure one async function is completed before another starts in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, async-await, fs

I'm new to this and might be missing something trivial.

```js
public async RunWorkFlow() {
    const zipFile = await DownloadZipFile(123, `abc`);
    await UnzipZippedArtifacts(zipFile);
}
```

When I'm trying to the above, sometimes the unzip method starts before downloading is completed, and causes in trying to unzip a corrupted (half-downloaded) file. Both the `DownloadZipFile` and `UnzipZippedArtifacts` are async methods, and I want to ensure that `DownloadZipFile` is completed before `UnzipZippedArtifacts` starts.

While unzipping, I get the error

`Error: Corrupted zip: can't find end of central directory` indicating that the file is not downloaded correctly.

---

```js
    private async DownloadZipFile(buildId: number, projectName: string) : Promise<string>
    {
        const buildApi = await this.api.getBuildApi();
        const artifactDetails = await buildApi.getArtifacts(buildId, projectName);
        const localZipFileName = buildId.toString() + `_` + artifactDetails[0]?.name + `_` + Date.now() + ".zip";
        const artifactStream = await buildApi.getArtifactContentZip(
            buildId, 
            artifactDetails[0]?.name, 
            projectName);

        const localZipFileStream = fs.createWriteStream(localZipFileName);
        await artifactStream
            .pipe(localZipFileStream)
            .on(`finish`, () => {
                localZipFileStream.close();
                this.logger.I(`Artifact zip file was download successfully for buildId ${buildId} in the project ${projectName}, filename is ${localZipFileName}`);                
            });
        
        return localZipFileName;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your `DownloadZipFile()`? Are you sure that the function ends when the file is completely downloaded or just when the download starts?

Comment: Added `DownloadZipFile()`

Comment: There's still a lot of code needed to understand/debug to issue, but check the value of `artifactStream` to make sure it's working correctly and if it's check the path in `createWriteStream` and one last thing your `DownloadZipFile()` is missing arguments when calling it

Comment: @MohamedOraby thanks! while debugging I noticed that the return statement executes before the `.on("finish")` method is called, any idea why it would be? I thought ideally await would make it fulfill the promise before moving to next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`artifactStream.pipe(localZipFileStream).on(...)` doesn't return a Promise so there's no point in `await`-ing it. It only registers a callback (the second argument in `on`) to be invoked when the "finish" event occurs.

In order to return a Promise from `DownloadZipFile` you need to wrap the `artifactStream.pipe(localZipFileStream).on(...)` in a Promise which will then be resolved when the callback function is invoked:

```
private async DownloadZipFile(buildId: number, projectName: string) : Promise < string >
{
    const buildApi = await this.api.getBuildApi();
    const artifactDetails = await buildApi.getArtifacts(buildId, projectName);
    const localZipFileName = buildId.toString() + `_` + artifactDetails[0]?.name + `_` + Date.now() + ".zip";
    const artifactStream = await buildApi.getArtifactContentZip(
        buildId,
        artifactDetails[0]?.name,
        projectName);

    const localZipFileStream = fs.createWriteStream(localZipFileName);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // resolve with location of saved file
        artifactStream
            .pipe(localZipFileStream)
            .on('finish', () => {
                localZipFileStream.close();
                this.logger.I(`Artifact zip file was download successfully for buildId ${buildId} in the project ${projectName}, filename is ${localZipFileName} `);

                resolve(localZipFileStream);
            });

    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! if you can, can you please clarify what was I trying to do that didn't work?

Comment: I've added a comment in the answer that might clarify it